# Why is Typescript not recognizing the type I'm giving to my `useState` state variables?

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, use-state

Why does the following code:

```
import React, {Dispatch, SetStateAction, useState} from 'react'

type Fn = () => void

export const Component = () => {
  const [fn, setFn]: [Fn, Dispatch<SetStateAction<Fn>>] = useState(() => {})

  return <p>{`${typeof fn}, ${typeof setFn}`}</p>
}
```

produce the following Typescript error:

> Type '[void, Dispatch<SetStateAction>]' is not assignable to type '[Fn, Dispatch<SetStateAction>]'.
>
> Type at position 0 in source is not compatible with type at position 0 in target.
>
> Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Fn'.ts(2322)
>
> const fn: Fn

?

You can see this in action yourself [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDeARYAZzBRjQAtsBlJGKmUpAQQ2AgDtsBXQpexgL5wAZlAgg4AciioMkgFDyYATzBI4AMXZwAvHAAUASl0A%20OADcIwACaKkAD0iw4aDoXgBhcZHZJ28PSNTXHk4Fzd4AG1hTjheGC0AXQAuOEitbAJiUgoAHho6BhhmVg5crRMTRN04Hj4ipH0gnTMcAUNFMJkYLihtXLATHAADABIcFTUIYRF2AWxxyaRpuNotAWGBXIB6QfkBIA)

The way I see it:

- I'm giving `useState` a default value of `() => {}` which is of type `() => void`.
- I'm declaring a `fn` constant of type `Fn` aka `() => void`
- These types are exactly the same and are NOT `void`

So why is Typescript referring to `Type '[void, Dispatch<SetStateAction>]`'?

Where is it getting that type from?

The only type I create (afaik) is `Type '[Fn, Dispatch<SetStateAction<Fn>>]'`, or am I doing something wrong?

As a follow-up question: is there perhaps a more succinct way of strictly typing this kind of thing?

Comment: @Woohaik Are you saying that in `const fn = () => {}` the function `fn` is not of type `() => void`? It's a function that doesn't return anything…

Comment: If you write a type for `() => {}` and another for `() => void`, use both in a different variable and then try to assign the variable one to another you will get `Type 'void' is not assignable to type '{}'`.

Comment: @Woohaik That's not what I'm doing in the code above. Rather, I'm declaring a function `() => {}` (on line 6 as the default value for `useState`) with type `() => void` (defined on line 3 as type `Fn`); something more like this: `const fn: () => void = () => {}; console.log(fn()) // prints 'undefined'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the type annotation, you'll see that the type for `fn` is inferred to be `void`:

[image]

This is happening because, if a function is passed to `useState`, [this is taken as a *callback* that React runs to determine the initial state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state). It's a way of not calling expensive processes that determine the initial state of every render.

If you want the state to be a function, you need to nest it inside another function.

```
const [fn, setFn] = useState(() => () => {})
```

No need to explicitly note the type - TypeScript can infer it automatically.

Comment: Ahh, I had forgotten this feature of `useState`. I thought I was misunderstanding Typescript itself. Now that I corrected the default value, I can indeed remove all of the type annotations and let Typescript infer them automatically.